# Fetching fetch the first occurrence from the result

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have an oracle sql query

```
select
    distinct 
    tab1.col1,
    tab2.col1
from 
    table1 tab1 
    join table2 tab2 on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
```

Here i get the as expected in terms of distinct values.

```
For Example : The result rows are

1  2 
3  4
5  6
```

Now I want to add one more join for table3. so my sql is

```
select
    distinct 
    tab1.col1,
    tab2.col1,
    tab3.col1
from 
    table1 tab1 
    join table2 tab2 on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
    join table3 tab3 on tab1.col1 = tab3.col1
```

Here what the problem is is that table 3 is returning more than one value.
which is resulting in duplicate rows based on table3.

```
For Example : The result rows are
1  2  4 
1  2  5 
3  4  1
3  4  2
5  6  3
```

(Here if you notice row 1 & 2 are duplicate and 3 & 4 are duplicate)

What I am trying to do is for the join of table3 i want to fetch the
first occurrence of row.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in the tables, the query result you get and the query result you would like to get?

Comment: I added the expected result above

Comment: Your join condition is "tab1.col1 = tab2.col1" and yet your example result set contains different values for them ...
Please provide create table statements with some sample data and the expected result set based on that sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shud work for you !

```
select 
    distinct  
    tab1.col1, 
    tab2.col1, 
    MIN(tab3.col1)
from  
    table1 tab1  
    join table2 tab2 on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1 
    join table3 tab3 on tab1.col1 = tab3.col1 
GROUP BY tab1.col1, tab2.col1
```

Edit: Thoughts,

I am assuming column 3 to be a integer which ever increasing, in that case this works. You can use the date column to define your aggregate accurately to get the "first occurance of your row".

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    distinct 
    tab1.col1,
    tab2.col1,
    t3.col1
from 
    table1 tab1 
    join table2 tab2 on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
    join (select distinct col1 from table3) t3 on tab1.col1 = t3.col1
```

Comment: I don't know the context. You should watch the EXPLAIN PLAN.

Comment: -1: DISTINCT returns distinct values across all the columns - this would only remove duplicates of all three columns.  See Baaju's answer for the correct way to handle what the OP asks for.